# MinGW on windows gcc compiler to create 64 Bit DLL for a nodejs (ffi-napi)

Tags: node.js, c, windows, gcc

I am using a  sample program from    https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi A Node.js Foreign Function    Interface for N-API factorial.c  is there a way to compile  a sample    C(factorial_lib.c) program as a windows 64Bit .DLL  I am using gcc    under windows( MinGW installed, not cygwin) ,
no luck: gives error, it seems the following is compiling it into    32BIT  need to know how to change the gcc default compilation into    64bit windows DLL
gcc -c -DBUILD_DLL factorial_lib.c
gcc -shared -o factorial.dll factorial_lib.o

PLEASE HELP , I have tried MS VSC compile and ran into issues

Comment: 32bit gcc will compile 32bit dll. You need the 64bit version of gcc to compile 64 bit dll

Comment: thankyou Nina, it is such a common Windows 64 bit format & MicroSoft Visual studio should have an option, All it now has is convoluted C# options , not even C++ options

Comment: Visual Studio does have an option to produce 32 bit or 64 bit binaries. You just need to make sure you have the SDK installed along with the C/C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW does not support 64-bit Windows. MinGW-w64 does support both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. You can download a standalone version from http://winlibs.com/.